# Run multiple Integration Tests that use Wiremock

Tags: c#, testing, integration-testing, specflow, wiremock

In my Specflow project i have a .features file with multiple test scenarios. the thing those tests have in common is that they all use a single Wiremock Server.

Now when I run the tests they always fail except for one. This problem also occurs when i deactivate parallel running in Ncrunch or VS testrunner.

I have tried running a single test while ignoring all the others, the test always passes so I came up with the conclusion that something is wrong with my wiremock server. Is there a special configuration needed for Wiremock server when running multiple scenarios in one .features file?

This is part of the specflow Hook File that sets up the tests:

```cs
public static void RegisterServices(ScenarioContext scenarioContext)
{
    WireMockServer httpBackend = RegisterWireMock(scenarioContext);
    // ...
    scenarioContext.Set(httpBackend);
}
private static WireMockServer RegisterWireMock(ScenarioContext scenarioContext)
{
    var httpBackend = WireMockServer.Start(new WireMockServerSettings()
    {
        UseSSL = false
    });
    scenarioContext.ScenarioContainer.RegisterInstanceAs(httpBackend, dispose: true);
    return httpBackend;
}
[BeforeScenario]
public static void Setup(ScenarioContext scenarioContext)
{
    RegisterServices(scenarioContext);
    /// ...
    var httpBackend = scenarioContext.Get<WireMockServer>();
    // Setup expectations for wiremock server ...
}
[AfterScenario]
public static void DisposeAll(ScenarioContext context)
{
    /// ...
    context.Get<WireMockServer>().Dispose();
}
```

```cs
// In this method, which is called during all integration tests,
// the tests fail because of a timeout. The timeout occurs because of
// the manual reset event never being set what should happen if the log
// entries of our wiremock server change. (and this works if you run the
// tests manually, one-by-one).
private void WaitForMessage(Predicate<ILogEntry> selector = null)
{
    var httpBackend = context.Get<WireMockServer>();
    using CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
    using ManualResetEventSlim waitHandle = new ManualResetEventSlim();
    httpBackend.LogEntriesChanged += (object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e) =>
    {
        if (selector == null)
        {
            waitHandle.Set(); // <----
            return;
    }
        /// ...
        foreach (ILogEntry item in e.NewItems)
        {
            if (selector(item))
            {
                waitHandle.Set(); // <----
                return;
            }
        }
    };
    waitHandle.Wait(cts.Token); // <---- TIMEOUT EXCEPTION LEADING TO FAILED TEST
    cts.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
}
```

Wiremock Server Settings:

```cs
11/9/2021 9:38:17 AM [Debug] : WireMock.Net server settings {
  "Port": null,
  "UseSSL": false,
  "StartAdminInterface": null,
  "ReadStaticMappings": null,
  "WatchStaticMappings": null,
  "WatchStaticMappingsInSubdirectories": null,
  "ProxyAndRecordSettings": null,
  "Urls": null,
  "StartTimeout": 10000,
  "AllowPartialMapping": null,
  "AdminUsername": null,
  "AdminPassword": null,
  "RequestLogExpirationDuration": null,
  "MaxRequestLogCount": null,
  "AllowCSharpCodeMatcher": null,
  "AllowBodyForAllHttpMethods": null,
  "AllowOnlyDefinedHttpStatusCodeInResponse": null,
  "DisableJsonBodyParsing": null,
  "DisableRequestBodyDecompressing": null,
  "HandleRequestsSynchronously": true,
  "ThrowExceptionWhenMatcherFails": null,
  "CertificateSettings": null,
  "CustomCertificateDefined": false,
  "WebhookSettings": null
}
```

Comment: Can you add information about what failures you're getting?

Comment: @agoff the infos were added.

Comment: Did you try this: https://github.com/WireMock-Net/WireMock.Net/wiki/Settings#handlerequestssynchronously

Comment: @StefHeyenrath Thank you for the useful tipp, However the tests are still failing. I added a logger to the settings. as a result the settings (above) were logged by all the tests. 
by the first test, which is passing were further infos also logged. However by the rest test (which are failing) there were no further info logged except for a Timout exception.